# Why is this code accessing vector out of its range?

Tags: c++, qt, stl

So, I'm trying bring over some code to a Qt project I'm working on. The Motion class imports some control points from .txt file into the public member variable `ctrlPos` using fstream. When I use `readCtrlPositions` and then try to access `ctrlPos` with `writePositions`, for example, I get the error "vector subscript out of range".

There is a lot more code, but hopefully this should be sufficient to answer my question. I'm also a bit of a novice, so with any luck it's not something too stupid.

Motion class header:

```
#ifndef MOTION_H
#define MOTION_H

#include <vector>

#include "DualQuaternion.h"

class Motion
{
public:
    virtual ~Motion();
    virtual void readCtrlPositions(char*, char*);
    virtual void writePositions(char*);
    virtual void drawCtrlPositions();
    virtual void set(int, vector<DualQuaternion>);
    virtual pair<int, vector<DualQuaternion>> get();

public:
    vector<DualQuaternion> ctrlPos, c;
    int numberOfPositions;

};

#endif
```

Motion class:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL\glut.h>

#include "motion.h"
#include "Quaternion.h"
#include "hMatrix.h"
#include "hPoint.h"

using namespace std;

void Motion::readCtrlPositions(char *fileNameArg, char *t)
{
    ifstream inFile(fileNameArg, ios::in);

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cerr<<"File" << fileNameArg << "could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int i;

    inFile >> numberOfPositions;

    Quaternion *RotationQuaternion = new Quaternion[numberOfPositions];

    for (i = 0; i<numberOfPositions; i++)
        inFile >> RotationQuaternion[i];

    if (t == "v")
    {
        Vector *TranslationVector = new Vector[numberOfPositions];
        for (i = 0; i<numberOfPositions; i++)
            inFile >> TranslationVector[i];
        ctrlPos.clear();
        for (i = 0; i<numberOfPositions; i++)
        {
            DualQuaternion dQ(RotationQuaternion[i], TranslationVector[i]);
            ctrlPos.push_back(dQ);
            cout << "first position from input: " << ctrlPos[i] << endl;
        }
        delete[] TranslationVector;
    }
    else if (t == "q")
    {
        Quaternion *TranslationQuaternion = new Quaternion[numberOfPositions];
        for (i = 0; i<numberOfPositions; i++)
            inFile >> TranslationQuaternion[i];
        ctrlPos.clear();
        for (i = 0; i<numberOfPositions; i++)
        {
            DualQuaternion dQ(RotationQuaternion[i], TranslationQuaternion[i]);
            ctrlPos.push_back(dQ);
            cout << "first position from input: " << ctrlPos[i] << endl;
        }
        delete[] TranslationQuaternion;
    }

    delete[] RotationQuaternion;

}

void Motion::writePositions(char *fileNameArg)
{
    ofstream outFile(fileNameArg, ios::out);

    if (!outFile)
    {
        cerr<<"File" << fileNameArg << "could not be opened for writing" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int i;

    outFile << numberOfPositions << endl << endl;

    for (i = 0; i<numberOfPositions; i++)
        outFile << ctrlPos[i].GetReal();
    outFile << endl;
    for (i = 0; i<numberOfPositions; i++)
        outFile << ctrlPos[i].GetDual();
}

void Motion::set(int n, vector<DualQuaternion> p)
{
    int i;
    numberOfPositions = n;
    ctrlPos.clear();
    for (i = 0; i<numberOfPositions; i++)
        ctrlPos.push_back(p[i]);
}

pair<int, vector<DualQuaternion>> Motion::get()
{
    return make_pair(numberOfPositions, ctrlPos);
}

void Motion::drawCtrlPositions()
{

    vector <hMatrix> homogeneousMatricesForCtrlPositions;
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfPositions; i++)
    {
        homogeneousMatricesForCtrlPositions.push_back(ctrlPos[i].dualQuaternionToHomogeneousMatrix().transpose());
        double MatrixforOpenGLStack[16];

        for (int i1=0; i1<4; i1++)
            for (int i2=0; i2<4; i2++)
                MatrixforOpenGLStack[4*i1+i2] =  homogeneousMatricesForCtrlPositions.at(i).m[i1][i2];

        ::glPushMatrix();
        ::glMultMatrixd(MatrixforOpenGLStack);
        glutSolidTeapot(0.15);
        ::glPopMatrix();
    }

}

Motion::~Motion()
{

}
```

Sample code where error occurs in Qt program:

```
static Curve m;
m.readCtrlPositions("input.txt", "v");
m.writePositions("output.txt"); //<--vector subscript out of range
m.readCtrlPositions("output.txt", "q");
ctrlPos = m.get().second;
numberOfPositions = m.get().first;
```

Comment: And? what does your debugger say? Where does that error occur? and if it's related to any of your constructs, at what index?

Comment: Have you checked if numberOfPositions was equal to ctrlPos.size() or not?

Comment: Does DualQuaternion have a valid copy constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `readCtrlPositions`, `t` is a `char*`, so nor `t=="v"`, nor `t=="q"` will be evaluated to `true` (it would return `true` if the two pointers were having the same address). So your function will set `numberOfPositions` to a non zero value but will never fill `ctrlPos` vector with any value.

Later, you'll try to access `ctrlPos` elements from `0` to `numberOfPositions` (not zero), while `ctrlPos` vector is empty.  That's why you are reported to access the vector out of its range!

Replace `char*` by `std::string` is an easy way to fix the problem. If you need to keep the parameter as a `char*`, then use `strcmp` to compare string values rather than pointers.

I would also strongly recommend that you remove your `numberOfPositions` attribute and simply use `ctrlPos.size()` instead. It would have prevented a crash in this case by guaranteeing your class attributes integrity.

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thank you. And I would ctrlPos.size() instead of numberOfPositions, but the input file changes size.

Comment: It changes both numberOfPositions and ctrlPos.size(). It makes no sense to maintain the two variables separately

Comment: So, when I first import the data from the .txt file, I don't know how many points there are in the file. If I don't have `numberOfPositions`, I don't know  how many times to iterate `inFile >> RotationQuaternion[i];`, `inFile >> TranslationVector[i];` or `inFile >> TranslationQuaternion[i];`. `ctrlPos.size()` is not the same value as `numberOfPositions` before the points are imported.

Comment: You can declare it locally, no need to make it be a class attribute.